# Determine similarity between atom distances in models

Tags: statistics

This is applied to bioinformatics, but I feel it is also a statistical question.

I have the x,y,z coordinates of 392 atoms in a 392-atom molecule.

There are 14 models of this molecule. In other words, 14 models of 392 x,y,z coordinates.

For each of the 14 models, I calculated the distance each atom has with all 391 other atoms. Then, I took the mean and stdev of the 392 vector of these distances.

Now, I have 14 mean and stdev values. I would like to perform some sort of statistical test to determine how "similar" the inter-atomic distances are between these 14 models.

What would be a possible test for this? I am speaking with my professor later, so no worries if it is no the "perfect

Comment: Rather than using using the means and stdevs, maybe you can use [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test) to compare (pairs of) your 14 distance distributions.